# problem with making background of image transparent: pygame

Tags: python, transparency, pygame, color-key

I'm in the middle of working on a simple typing tutor using pygame.  My problem is that I'm using an image that has a white background, `waves1.png`.  Now's I've specified that I want white to be transparent in the image (`self.image.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))`) and it is for everything except the text block.  When the waves intersect with the `text` object, the white background of the waves show on top of the text.  You can try running this if you have pygame (with the exception of the waves1.png image).

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class TextSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.wordList = ['words yes', 'hello', 'this is a sentence', 'this is another sentence'] # read directly from external file
        self.pos = 0
        self.wordNum = 0
        self.update1()

    def update1(self):
        # Render the given word
        self.image = pygame.font.Font(None, 36).render(self.wordList[self.wordNum], 1, (0, 0, 0))
        # Render the correctly guessed letters
        self.correct = pygame.font.Font(None, 36).render(self.wordList[self.wordNum][:self.pos], 1, (255, 0, 0))
        # Copy correct letters onto given word
        self.image.blit(self.correct, (0, 0))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # set the center of the center the given word to the center of the screen
        self.rect.center = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().center

    def keyin(self, key):
        word = self.wordList[self.wordNum]
        letter = word[self.pos]
        if letter == key:
            self.pos = self.pos + 1
        if self.pos == len(word):
            self.reset()
        self.update1()

    def reset(self):
        self.pos = 0
        self.wordNum = self.wordNum + 1
        self.update1()



class Waves(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # Constructor. Pass in the color of the block, 
    # and its x and y position
    def __init__(self, filename):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
        # makes any white in the image transparent
        self.image.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    # Decrease the y coordinate so the waves look like they're moving up
    def update(self, text):
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y - 6
        if self.rect.y <= 200:
            text.reset()
            self.rect.y = 485


def main():

    #I - Import and initialize
    pygame.init()

    #D - Display configuration
    # The screen variable is a pygame Surface object
    # Note that the set_mode() method creates a Surface object for you automatically
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Typing Game")

    #E - Entities (just background for now)
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))



    #A - Action (broken into ALTER steps)

    #A - Assign values to key variables
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    keepGoing = True

    # Collect the sprite in a list
    all = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain()
    waveList = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain()

    text = TextSprite()
    all.add(text)

    waves = Waves("waves1.png")
    waveList.add(waves)
    waves.rect.x = 0
    waves.rect.y = 485

    #L - Set up main loop
    while keepGoing:

        #T - Timer to set frame rate
        # Tick is a method in the Clock class that determines the maximum frame rate
        clock.tick(30)

        #E - Event handling
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                keepGoing = False
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    keepGoing = False
                else:
                    text.keyin(event.unicode)

        # update position of waves
        waves.update(text)

        # clears screen
        all.clear(screen, background)

        # update screen
        all.draw(screen)

        waveList.clear(screen, background)
        waveList.draw(screen)


        # display.flip is a method that copies everything from the screen object to the actual visual display
        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit ()
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's an option for you, but you should get better results with png's native alpha transparency.

If you can edit/recreate the png yourself, then try using a transparent background.

From there, you can use convert_alpha() arfter loading the image. (instead of using a colorkey)

http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.convert_alpha

**EDIT:** one other aspect, is that the image may have an alpha channel interfering with the colorkey. Best to ensure you're not trying to use both.

I'm told that you can detect an image's alpha channel programmatically. Something like ...

```
 if self.image.get_masks()[3]!=0:
   print "image has alpha!"
```

See here http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.get_masks

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Well done! You've actually done everything correctly to take advantage of transparency and colorkey (ie, making sure to call convert on the surface, making sure to pass the color into the set_colorkey method, etc).

The problem is with the order of calls to draw and clear on your respective sprite groups, "all" and "waveList". After you've rendered the text blocks by calling all.draw, you then follow it with the call to waveList.clear.

Here's the problem: once you've drawn the text sprites, you don't want to clear the space underneath the wave sprites, or that will wipe out the area that overlaps the already-drawn text blocks.

If you want to do this properly, try doing it in this order:

1. waves.update()
2. all.clear(screen,background)
3. waveList.clear(screen,background)
4. all.draw(screen)
5. waveList.draw(screen)

(more simply, just move waveList.clear(screen, background) to the line just below all.clear(screen, background); that should do it)

When I'm working with sprite groups, I usually try to group it so that each sprite group calls the same method in this order: clears, updates, collision checks (if any), draws.

This usually handles things in the right order. Then you still may have to pay attention to whether there is any layering of sprites, but that's another story for another day.